# Unable to read a searched result using selenium 2.0

Tags: java, selenium

I am running a java converted selenium 2.0 script using JDev. I have a case wherein I open a modal window and search for a string like `%SomeText%` and it results a record just below it, w/n the same window. Now, I want to make sure that that it has resulted the text I am looking for, and click OK in the modal window if I get that text. Any ideas how to do it...I am doing the following:

```
//this is working
driver.findElement(By.id("_afrFilterpt1_afr__UISatr_afr_0_afr_AT1_afr__ATp_afr_t2_afr_c3::content")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN); 

//this doesn't work, text given here is part of the text which is returned after search
assertTrue((driver.findElements(By.xpath("contains(text(),'Approved:Create Grade Ladder (AU_New Grade Ladder205, 2012-08-31)')")).size() > 0) ? true:false); 

//this works if above line is deleted, else this also does not work
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='OK']")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can write line 2 is driver.getPageSource().contains(text);

Secondly, your xpath is incorrect as it is looking for the root node to contain "Approved:Create Grade Ladder (AU_New Grade Ladder205, 2012-08-31)" as a reference node hasn't been provided to the xpath.

In short that says you are looking for for markup to look like this:

```
<html>
  Approved:Create Grade Ladder (AU_New Grade Ladder205, 2012-08-31)
</html>
```

If you learned xpath off of w3schools, this may sound kinda confusing but it's much like directories.

By default your reference starts at /, therefore, the tag  would have to contain the text you are searching for this to happen. in addition to this, text() only gives you the text of the current node and none of the nodes below it.

Take the following example

```
<html>
  <body>
   <div>Some text <span>with a span</span>.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you did `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Some text with a span.')]")).size();` You would find that it would equal 0.

You can see why if you just select the text node using xpath. See image below:
[image: Xpath Example]